# Keeping a navbar (unorderd list) inside the header

Tags: html, css

You can see my problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/jonese1234/rnbphm4x/

The problem is my nav bar will not sit inside the div/header, i have tryed many methods but i can not get it to work, so i hope somebody can spot my error.

i believe its something to do with:

```
.nav li {
    float:left;
    width: 25%; /* Split width appropriately */
}

.nav a:link, a:visited {
    display:block;
```

It is also ment to have each button cover 25% of the width, however when if it manage to get it inside the div/header it never covers the whole width.

Comment: There are many way to do this, but if you use `float`, like you do, you should `clear` too.

Comment: give your header a height